# Two metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$ on $X$ are equivalent iff for each $A \subseteq X$, $d_1(x,A) = 0 \iff d_2(x,A) = 0 (x\in X)$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, metric-spaces

I did the forward direction of this question. And my proof looks like this:

Suppose $d_1(x,A) = 0$, where $x\in X$. So every $d_1$neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$. That is $B_{d_1}(x,r)\cap A$ $\neq$ $\emptyset$, $\forall r\gt0$.

Now let $B_{d_2}(x,s)$ be any open ball, where $x\in X$.

Now as the two metrics are equivalent so $\exists$ a number $t \gt 0$ such that $B_{d_1}(x,t) \subseteq B_{d_2}(x,s).$ Now intersecting $A$ in both the sides we get that: $B_{d_1}(x,t) \cap A \subseteq B_{d_2}(x,s) \cap A.$ And we know that $B_{d_1}(x,t)\cap A \neq \emptyset$, so evidently $B_{d_2}(x,s) \cap A \neq \emptyset$. So every $d_2$ neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$ and hence we get that $d_2(x,A) = 0$. Similarly we will get that if $d_2(x,A) = 0$ then $d_1(x,A)=0$.

Now my question is how to solve the other direction of the proof?

Comment: I like this question a lot, I had never heard of this reformulation of metric equivalence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the other direction, letting $x \in X$ and $s > 0$ be given, we shall find $t > 0$ so that $B_{d_1}(x,t) \subset B_{d_2}(x,s)$. (The other half of the proof of equivalence of metrics is similar, just by swapping the roles of the subscripts $1$ and $2$).

We'll find $t$ by making a useful choice of $A$, namely
$$A = X - B_{d_2}(x,s)
$$
It follows that
$$d_2(x,A) \ge s
$$
because otherwise, if $d_2(x,A) < s$, then using that $d_2(x,A) = \inf \{d_2(x,a) \mid a \in A\}$, one can find $a \in A$ such that $d_2(x,a) < s$. This would imply that $a \in B_{d_2}(x,s)$, contradicting that $B_{d_2}(x,s) \cap A = \emptyset$.

Now, knowing that $d_2(x,A) \ge s > 0$, it follows that $d_1(x,A) > 0$. Setting $t = d_1(x,A)$, consider the ball $B_{d_1}(x,t)$. Since $B_{d_1}(x,t) \cap A = \emptyset$ it follows that
$$B_{d_1}(x,t) \subset X-A = B_{d_2}(x,s)
$$

Comment: This proof is perfect. But I have a question… Is it necessary to define the $\epsilon$? I think one can directly conclude $d_2(x,a)<s$, i.e. $a\in B_{d_2}(x,s)$

Comment: Because we know that $d_2(x,A)$=inf {$d_2(x,a): a \in A$}

Comment: Ah, yes, that's simpler. I'll edit my answer.